# HTML control's event won't fire?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm having trouble firing or capturing the results of an event firing.

Here's the current code...

```
<s:Panel id="instructionsPanel" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" title="Register">
    <mx:HTML id="htmlViewer" left="10" right="10" top="0" bottom="10"
             location="http://ramzsoft.com/software-optins/easyspinner.html"/>
    <s:TextInput id="urlOutput" x="10" y="285" width="628" text="Not a test"/>
</s:Panel>

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

import org.osmf.utils.URL;

private var file:File = new File();
private const FIRST_RUN_TOKEN_FILE:File =
    File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("firstrun");

init();

private function init():void {
    htmlViewer.addEventListener(Event.LOCATION_CHANGE, onClosePanel);
}

private function onClosePanel(e:Event) {
    urlOutput.text = "test";
    instructionsPanel.visible = false;
}
```

What's happening is that the user fills out a form in the HTML Viewer, then when they click the submit button I want to be notified of the page change.

If they land on URL A, then they'll be shown one message. If they land on URL B, they'll be shown another.

However, the event isn't firing.

I've also tried COMPLETE and HTML_DOM_INITIALIZE.

Any ideas on why this isn't working right?

Comment: What version of Flex SDK are you using?

Comment: Ok that must be the AIR SDK version but in fact that's what I wanted to know. I know some events where introduced in AIR 2.7 for the HmlLoader (notably LOCATION_CHANGING) but I think LOCATION_CHANGE should work. What kind of object is htmlViewer?

Comment: It's an mx:HTML control. The events I've tried were pulled from Adobe's docs on the control.

Comment: Try setting the listener on the inner HtmlLoader (htmlViewer.htmlLoader). It should work on the mx:HTML control but let's give it a try anyway. Also, I have to set -swf-version=12 in my compilation settings for all events to fire correctly in AIR 2.7 so you might want to try -swf-version=11 or even -swf-version=12

Comment: After looking a bit further, it looks like my init function isn't running at all. I explicitly call it but it doesn't get run... This is weird.

Comment: Can you post more code then please?

Comment: I modified the original post with more code. That's everything that relates to the items in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure putting init(); in the middle of nowhere has any effects. Anyways, you don't need that init, you can set it directly throught MXML. By the way, I think location change is not dispatched when you manually set the location the the HTML component, only when clicking on links (or redirections).

```
<s:Panel id="instructionsPanel" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" title="Register">
    <mx:HTML id="htmlViewer" left="10" right="10" top="0" bottom="10"
             location="http://ramzsoft.com/software-optins/easyspinner.html"
             locationChange="onClosePanel(event)"/>
    <s:TextInput id="urlOutput" x="10" y="285" width="628" text="Not a test"/>
</s:Panel>
```